# Create custom extension

Tags: twig, slim

I have created a template manager with `Slim+Twig` and it works well. The problem is when trying to add an Extension, I get an error when calling the extension from the `.twig` file, and I don't know exactly what the error could be:

**index.php**

```php
<?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Slim\Views\TwigMiddleware;

use Helpers\PaginatorTwigExtension;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Create App
$app = AppFactory::create();

// Create Twig
$twig = Twig::create('path/to/templates', ['cache' => false]);

// Add Twig-View Middleware
$app->add(TwigMiddleware::create($app, $twig));

$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) use () {
    $view = Twig::fromRequest($request);

    return $view->render($response, 'index.twig', []);
});

// Run app
$app->run();
```

**PaginatorTwigExtension.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Helpers;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

/**
 * Twig extension to help generate simple paginations.
 */
class PaginatorTwigExtension extends AbstractExtension
{

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'paginator';
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('paginator', [$this, 'generatePaginationData']),
        ];
    }

    public function generatePaginationData(int $curr_page, int $last_page, int $num_items = 7, string $separator = '...')
    {
        return array(
            'curr_page' => $curr_page,
            'last_page' => $last_page,
            'num_items' => $num_items,
            'separator' => $separator,
            'pagination' => $pagination
        );
    }
}
```

When calling the extension from the `index.twig` file, I do it like this:

```
{% set paginator = paginator(10, 25 , 11, '...') %}
```

But it gives me this error:

> Unknown "paginator" function.

My question is, am I missing something to include this custom extension? Or should we call it something else?

Comment: You still need to [register](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html#creating-an-extension) the extension as seen in the linked documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the extension via the addExtension() method:

```php
$twig->addExtension(new \Helpers\PaginatorTwigExtension());
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I get this error: Uncaught Error: Class "Helpers\PaginatorTwigExtension" not found

Comment: It should work if the namespace `\Helpers` is correctly configured in your composer.json `autoload > psr-4` section. See [here](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html#autoloader).

Comment: Yes, I was missing that part, thank you